# ehcache with 'attempted VM halt' on re-deploy since upgrade to Tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, ehcache

We've recently upgraded our Tomcat 8 to Tomcat 9.0.31. Since then, re-deploying our Spring Boot application brings down the entire JVM (it seems). The culprit seems to be ehCache, but I can't find any references, nobody else seems to be having the same problem.

Tomcat 9.0.31 is running two Spring Boot web applications (one for testing, one for demos), same application, but possibly on different versions. On the earlier Tomcat 8.5.47 version, re-deployments didn't cause any problem.

The error I get is

```
[2023-04-11 16:23:29] [info] 14:23:28.917 [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-22] INFO ch.want.myapp.MyappApp - Starting MyappApp
[2023-04-11 16:23:37] [info]   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[2023-04-11 16:23:37] [info]  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[2023-04-11 16:23:37] [info] ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[2023-04-11 16:23:37] [info]  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[2023-04-11 16:23:37] [info]   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[2023-04-11 16:23:37] [info]  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[2023-04-11 16:23:37] [info]  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)
[2023-04-11 16:32:04] [info] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8089"]
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [info] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [info] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Error deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/purple.war]
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1641)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1590)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:846)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:454)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:415)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/purple]]
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 39 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminToolsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jCacheCacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'jCacheCacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Cache 'getAccountSettingByState' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 40 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jCacheCacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'jCacheCacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Cache 'getAccountSettingByState' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 63 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'jCacheCacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Cache 'getAccountSettingByState' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.lambda$instantiate$2(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 76 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Cache 'getAccountSettingByState' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner$Transition.failed(StatusTransitioner.java:235)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.init(EhcacheManager.java:605)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.createCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:159)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:134)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:85)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration.createCacheManager(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:101)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheCacheConfiguration.jCacheCacheManager(JCacheCacheConfiguration.java:83)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 79 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache 'getAccountSettingByState' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createCache(EhcacheManager.java:302)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.init(EhcacheManager.java:584)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 89 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Error: attempted VM halt
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner$Transition.succeeded(StatusTransitioner.java:209)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheBase.init(EhcacheBase.java:569)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.createCache(EhcacheManager.java:275)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 90 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Error: attempted VM halt
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.paging.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.uninterruptibleGet(UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.java:602)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.paging.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.allocateBackingBuffers(UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.java:525)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.paging.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.<init>(UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.java:152)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.paging.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.<init>(UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.java:119)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.OffHeapStore.createBackingMap(OffHeapStore.java:103)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.OffHeapStore.access$500(OffHeapStore.java:69)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.OffHeapStore$Provider.init(OffHeapStore.java:222)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.OffHeapStore$Provider.initStore(OffHeapStore.java:218)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.offheap.OffHeapStore$Provider.initAuthoritativeTier(OffHeapStore.java:254)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.tiering.TieredStore$Provider.initStore(TieredStore.java:544)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager$7.init(EhcacheManager.java:509)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner.runInitHooks(StatusTransitioner.java:135)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner.access$000(StatusTransitioner.java:33)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner$Transition.succeeded(StatusTransitioner.java:194)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 92 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Error: attempted VM halt
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.paging.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.uninterruptibleGet(UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.java:597)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 105 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit] Caused by: java.lang.Error: attempted VM halt
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.buffersource.TimingBufferSource.commitSuicide(TimingBufferSource.java:88)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.buffersource.TimingBufferSource.allocateBuffer(TimingBufferSource.java:51)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.paging.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.bufferAllocation(UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.java:559)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at org.ehcache.shadow.org.terracotta.offheapstore.paging.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.lambda$allocateBackingBuffers$1(UpfrontAllocatingPageSource.java:513)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [crit]     ... 1 more
[2023-04-11 16:32:05] [info] Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/purple.war] has finished in [560,726] ms
[2023-04-11 16:32:06] [info] Stopping service [Catalina]
```

The ehcache (3.9.0) configuration is rather simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'  
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>  

  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults enable-statistics="true" />
  </service>

  <cache alias="countryByCode" uses-template="staticDataCache"/>
  <cache alias="countrySearch" uses-template="staticDataCache"/>
  <cache alias="locationByCode" uses-template="staticDataCache"/>
  <cache alias="getBestFit" uses-template="staticDataCache"/>
  <cache alias="PropertySecurityManager.unwriteableProperties" uses-template="staticDataCache"/>
  <cache alias="PropertySecurityManager.serverSideProperties" uses-template="staticDataCache"/>
  
  <cache alias="getSystemSettings" uses-template="oneDayCache"/>
  <cache alias="getSystemSettingsFeatures" uses-template="oneDayCache"/>
  <cache alias="getSystemSettingsByKey" uses-template="oneDayCache"/>
  <cache alias="getExchangeRate" uses-template="oneDayCache"/>
  
  <cache alias="loadUserByUsername" uses-template="dynamicCache"/>
  <cache alias="getChildOrganizationUuids" uses-template="dynamicCache"/>
  <cache alias="getParentOrganizationUuids" uses-template="dynamicCache"/>
  <cache alias="getAllOrganizations" uses-template="dynamicCache"/>
  <cache alias="getAccountSettingByState" uses-template="dynamicCache"/>
  <cache alias="getAccountSettingByMetadata" uses-template="dynamicCache"/>
  <cache alias="locationSearch" uses-template="dynamicCache"/>
  
  <cache-template name="staticDataCache">
    <expiry>
      <none />
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">100</heap>
  </cache-template>
  
  <cache-template name="oneDayCache">
    <expiry>
      <ttl unit="hours">24</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">50</heap>
  </cache-template>

  <cache-template name="dynamicCache">
    <expiry>
      <ttl unit="minutes">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <resources>
      <heap unit="entries">100</heap> 
      <offheap unit="MB">50</offheap> 
    </resources>
  </cache-template>
</config>
```

Based on the fact that it only happens on re-deploy I assume the cause is somewhere in resources not being closed. If this is a known issue with ehCache + Tomcat9, there must be a bug report out there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
<offheap unit="MB">50</offheap>
```

from ehcache.xml seems to resolve the issue.